# ValueError: Invalid salt in bcrypt python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bcrypt

I'm having some issues with this code, because I try to verify that the password entered by the user and the one in the database are the same, but every time it raises a `ValueError: Invalid salt` exception at the line commented down below, because the salt given to verify the password is, for some reason, not valid. I've read the docs so many times and still I couldn't manage to find the problem, anyone that could help me?

```
from bcrypt import hashpw, checkpw, gensalt

with ps.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(
                    f'''SELECT password from "'{self.email.text}'" WHERE email = '{self.email.text}' ''')
                credentials = cur.fetchone()

                crypted_pw = f"{credentials[0]}".encode()
                password_enc = f"{password}".encode()

                if checkpw(password_enc, crypted_pw):  # Here should be the error
                    self.valid = True
                    return self.valid
                else:
                    self.valid = False
                    return self.valid
```

Comment: By passing the ```password``` as default arg, you are ensuring that this is OK, but what about the ```crypted_pw``` that comes from the credentials?. Do you print that value to debug?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain?